# Fastest, easiest installer from web?

Tags: installation

- I have a file that is an executable (.exe) that I want to distribute
- I want users to run it as simply as humanly possible
- Is there a way to simplify this process, with different technologies (eg, Java) assisting along the way?

**Current Situation**

*Internet Explorer*

1. User downloads in the regular way
2. User clicks run
3. User clicks run again
4. User gives UAC permission

*Firefox*

1. User downloads in the regular way
2. Opens saved items
3. Double clicks the installer
4. Gives permission to run the installer
5. Grants UAC permission

It may not seem like long process to an experienced user, but to an inexperienced one this can feel like an eternity.

Is there a faster, easier way to pull this off?

Comment: The reason for this is that user won't accidentally run something unsafe downloaded from the internet. So the browsers are actively enforcing that many steps, which means there is no "legit way" to bypass it, although there may be some tricks. It can be a long shot, but lookup MS code signing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx .It is possible that signed binaries use simpler runnning algorithm, at least in IE.

Comment: Binaries are already signed -- that's the second "Run" prompt. :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to simplify that process sounds like taking control and security away from user. Only simpler thing I can imagine is to use Java applet or web application instead of executable file.

Comment: Would love to, but can't use an applet.  Need to work outside of the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you install file to some per-user location like under %userprofile%\ and installer does nothing except deploying executable and/or probably create shortcut in current user's area that should not require elevated privileges. Also signing application (or installer) with a valid certificate may allow you to avoid UAC interaction.

I really doubt you may greatly simplify the process because it may be a thread to a system.